# add additional responsive tabs button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I've got these responsive tabs.

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Tab01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab02</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab03</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab04</a></li>
</ul> 
<div class="tab_content">

    <div class="tabs_item">
        <h4>Tab 01</h4>
        <p>Tab 01</p>
    </div>
 etc. etc.
```

These all work. If you were to add a 5th list item, and a 5th div, everything would work perfectly fine and you'd have a new tab item with tab content for that item when you click on it.

Here's the code for all that:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

(function ($) { 
    $('.tab ul.tabs').addClass('active').find('> li:eq(0)').addClass('current');

    $('.tab ul.tabs li a').click(function (g) { 
        var tab = $(this).closest('.tab'), 
            index = $(this).closest('li').index();

        tab.find('ul.tabs > li').removeClass('current');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');

        tab.find('.tab_content').find('div.tabs_item').not('div.tabs_item:eq(' + index + ')').slideUp();
        tab.find('.tab_content').find('div.tabs_item:eq(' + index + ')').slideDown();

        g.preventDefault();
    } );
})(jQuery);

});
```

Now I've got a second js file as well. This one is to add additional list items into my tabs. Essentially, you click a button, and

```
$(tabs).append('<li><a href="#">Tab05</a></li>');
```

happens. Now this works, kinda. You get a new list item that says Tab05. You check the HTML and it's exactly the same as the other list items. However, it does nothing when you click on it. It doesn't activate as a responsive tab. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery selectors select matching elements that exist in the DOM when the code is executed. they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

As you are dynamically adding tabs

```
$(tabs).append('<li><a href="#">Tab05</a></li>');
```

You need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Example

```
$(document).on('click', '.tab ul.tabs li a', function(){
    //Your code
});
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Comment: I created a third js file, copy pasted the code of the first js file inside a click event. And it still doesn't work.

Clicking the button adds a new tab in the 2nd js file, and recalls the code of the first js file in the third one. But yea it doesn't work.